# Regex for search and replace in vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I have a file which has multiple entries like this:

```
Abcd:abcd:*sometext*:klm:xyz/abc
Abcd:abcd:R%fs90uw:klm:xyz/abc
```

Now, I want to replace "klm" with "qrs" for only those lines which have the "*sometext*" string in the line.

How can I do this using the search and replace feature in vim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:g` is your friend:

```
:g/sometext/s/klm/qrs/g
```

Comment: How about change entries only when *sometext* is NOT present?

Comment: I got that. It should be :v.

Answer (score 0):

Also a substitution command can do the job:

```
:%s/\(sometext.*\)klm/\1qrs/g
```