# Search and replace using vim

Tags: vim

I have opened a document using vim (only text editor available on my install of linux) and I need to search and replace all instances of BGA to CGA

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

The file is listed below:

```
select comments,* from LOGS where barcode in ('BGA001248788','BGA000632039','BGA001270649','BGA000997171','BGA000997172','BGA000265968','BGA000265964','BGA000720466','BGA000720467','BGA002224291','BGA002224292','BGA000726647','BGA000609927','BGA000609928',
'BGA000504740', 'BGA000702736','BGA000547632','BGA000583033','BGA000583034','BGA000632053','BGA000225618','BGA001248788','BGA000632039','BGA001270649','BGA000997171','BGA000997172','BGA000265968','BGA000265964','BGA000720466','BGA000720467','BGA002224291','BGA002224292','BGA000726647','BGA000609927',
'BGA000609928','BGA000504740', 'BGA000702736','BGA000547632','BGA000583033','BGA000583034','BGA000632053','BGA000225618','BGA001248788','BGA000632039','BGA001270649','BGA000997171','BGA000997172','BGA000265968','BGA000265964','BGA000720466','BGA000720467','BGA002224291','BGA002224292','BGA000726647',
'BGA000609927','BGA000609928','BGA000504740', 'BGA000702736','BGA000547632','BGA000583033','BGA000583034','BGA000632053','BGA000225618','BGA001248788','BGA000632039','BGA001270649','BGA000997171','BGA000997172','BGA000265968','BGA000265964','BGA000720466','BGA000720467','BGA002224291','BGA002224292','BGA000726647','BGA000609927','BGA000609928','BGA000504740', 'BGA000702736','BGA000547632','BGA000583033','BGA000583034','BGA000632053','BGA000225618','BGA001248788','BGA000632039','BGA001270649',
'BGA000997171','BGA000997172','BGA000265968','BGA000265964','BGA000720466','BGA000720467','BGA002224291','BGA002224292','BGA000726647','BGA000609927','BGA000609928','BGA000504740', 'BGA000702736','BGA000547632','BGA000583033','BGA000583034','BGA000632053','BGA000225618')
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should have tried Google first. There have been loads of blog posts, help in Vim, etc. about search and replace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for search and replace in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063324/regex-for-search-and-replace-in-vim)

Comment: I think `ed` the standard editor should be at your disposal too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform a blanket search and replace on the buffer(file) you have open in vi(m) then do the following:

1) Press the escape key twice to ensure you are at the "ready for a command" 
2) type:

```
%s/BGA/CGA/gi
```

Line 2 is broken down below:

```
:    - tells vi to expect a command
%s   - tells vi to use the substitute command
/    - separator to tell vi that the search string is next
BCA  - the search string to search for
/    - tells vi that the search string is terminated and to expect the replacement string
CGA  - the replacement string
/    - tells vi that the replacement string is terminated
g    - g = global, all references in the buffer, if this is omitted then only the first instance from the cursor position is replaced
i    - i = ignore case
```

Hope that answers your question!

Once you've mastered vi(m) there's no going back!!

Answer (score 2):

In normal mode `:%s/BGA/CGA/gc` where:

- `%` means all lines
- `s` is an alias for `substitute` command
- `g` means replace more than 1 time per line
- `c` ask action

This will ask you if you want to:

- Replace (y)
- Pass (n)
- Replace all (a)
- Stop (q)
- And more

More explaination [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) or (in normal mode) `:help subs`